# Converting Non-UTF-8 characters to UTF-8

Tags: python, c, linux

I have some files which are present on my Linux system. These files names can be other the un_eng-utf8. I want to convert them from non-utf8 character to the utf-8 character. How can I do that using C library function or python scripts.

Comment: Do you know the original encoding? Are all characters available in UTF-8 or do you want to replace the unavailable with similar ones, ignore them or do something else about them?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the character encoding that is used to encode the filenames:

```
unicode_filename = bytestring_filename.decode(character_encoding)
utf8filename = unicode_filename.encode('utf-8')
```

If you don't know the character encoding then there is no way in the general case to do the conversion without loosing data -- "non-utf8" is not specific enough e.g., if you have a filename that contains `b'\xae'` byte then it can be interpreted differently depending on the filename encoding -- it is **`u'®'`** in `cp1252` encoding but *the same byte* represents **`u'«'`** in `cp437`. There are modules such as `chardet` that allow you to guess the character encoding but it is only *a guess* -- ["There Ain't No Such Thing as Plain Text."](http://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/)

Answer (score 0):

```
def converttoutf8(a):
    return unicode(a, "utf-8")
```

now for every filename you iterate through, that will return the utf-8 formatted filename

or even better, use [convmv](http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/).  it converts filenames from one encoding to another and takes a directory as an argument.  sounds perfect.

Comment: your code assumes that `a` bytestring is encoded using utf-8 encoding. OP explicitly says that input is not utf-8.