# UnicodeEncodeError when reading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to read from rockyou wordlist and write all words that are >= 8 chars to a new file.

Here is the code -

```
def main():
    with open("rockyou.txt", encoding="utf8") as in_file, open('rockout.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if len(line.rstrip()) < 8:
                continue
            print(line, file = out_file, end = '')
        print("done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Some words are not utf-8.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wpa_rock.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "wpa_rock.py", line 6, in main
    print(line, file = out_file, end = '')
  File "C:\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0e45' in position
0: character maps to <undefined>`

**Update**

````
def main():
with open("rockyou.txt", encoding="utf8") as in_file, open('rockout.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if len(line.rstrip()) < 8:
            continue
        out_file.write(line)
    print("done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wpa_rock.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "wpa_rock.py", line 3, in main
    for line in in_file:
  File "C:\Python\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 933: invali
d continuation byte`

Comment: It's a typo. It should be `utf-8` instead of `utf8`

Comment: I don't know if it is. Using either results into same error.

Comment: You must have an invalid character at that position. You should show the file you are attempting to read.

Comment: @Arpan: no, it isn't. Either `'utf8'` or `'utf-8'` works, one is an alias for the other.

Comment: This is an **encoding** error. You didn't include the full traceback, but this is the **`print()`** call that throws this error, not reading the file.

Comment: @Arpan It's a big wordlist ~130mb. I found similar issue https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan/issues/190

Comment: @MarkEvans: that error is not related. For one, that's a *Ruby* error, and secondly, that's a *decoding* error from UTF-8. You are encoding Unicode to CP1252, because your Windows console is configured for that characterset (the Windows Latin-1 variant).

Comment: @MarkEvans: see the dupe. Printing to the windows console is problematic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I didn't know that! Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not a dupe. The OP writes to file.

Comment: @MarkEvans have you tried to add `encoding="utf8"` when opening the output file. I have no windows machine  now, so I can't check.

Comment: I did. But all of that results in encode error at some point. (The above code writes ~700kb, using utf-8 in `open` it writes ~2mb, but still gives the error)

Comment: Right, I missed this is printing to a file. You didn't specify an encoding for that file so the system default applies. Add  an explicit encoding argument.

Comment: @MarkEvans: then include that new error in your question.

Comment: related: [Why doesn't this conversion to utf8 work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7163485/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap'` error occurs during *writing* to `out_file` (in `print()`).

By default, `open()` uses `locale.getpreferredencoding()` that is ANSI codepage on Windows (such as `cp1252`) that can't represent all Unicode characters and `'\u0e45'` character in particular. `cp1252` is a one-byte encoding that can represent at most `256` different characters but there are a million (`1114111`) Unicode characters. It can't represent them all.

Pass `encoding` that can represent all the desired data e.g., `encoding='utf-8'` must work (as [@robyschek suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633927/unicodeencodeerror-when-reading-a-file?noredirect=1#comment62750292_37633927))—if your code reads `utf-8` data without any errors then the code should be able to write the data using `utf-8` too.

---

Your `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'` error occurs during reading `in_file` (`for line in in_file`). Not all byte sequences are valid utf-8 e.g., `os.urandom(100).decode('utf-8')` may fail. What to do depends on the application.

If you expect the file to be encoded as utf-8; you could pass `errors="ignore"` `open()` parameter, to ignore occasional invalid byte sequences. Or you could use [some other error handlers depending on your application](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).

If the actual character encoding used in the file is different then you should pass the actual character encoding. `bytes` by themselves do not have any encoding—that metadata should come from another source (though [some encodings are more likely than others: `chardet` can *guess*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33100182/4279)) e.g., if the file content is an http body then see [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279)

Sometimes a broken software can generate mostly utf-8 byte sequences with some bytes in a different encoding. [`bs4.BeautifulSoup` can handle some special cases](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#inconsistent-encodings). You could also [try `ftfy` utility/library](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#command-line-tool) and see if it helps in your case e.g., [`ftfy` may fix some utf-8 variations](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-ftfy.bad_codecs.utf8_variants).

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was having a similar issue, in the case of `rockyou.txt` wordlist, I tried a number of encodings that Python had to offer and I found that `encoding = 'kio8_u'` worked to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me, but I found that adding `errors='replace'` to `open()` fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).